# Spring Boot - How Another Microservice Validate JwT Token when 2 Microservice communicate each other

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I am having trouble finding answers. When I have two Spring Boot Microservice applications, Microservice A and Microservice B, and they both communicate with each other, I encounter an issue. When Microservice A generates a JWT Token after authentication and sends a response to Microservice B, along with the JWT Token, how does Microservice B validate the JWT token to ensure its validity? I understand that Microservice A already validated the JWT Token, but when it sends the JwT token, Microservice B also needs to validate it upon receipt. Could someone please help me with the answers and provide examples to help me understand? Additionally, if there are any Google resources available, please share them here as they would be helpful for my learning session. Thank you

Comment: You can handle it with writing an interceptor in your Microservice B and when you send request from A to B put JWT token in your header and decode your token in B and check that token is valid or not . also you can use SSO for automate this flow . spring has own SSO named spring Authorization server that implements OAUTH 2.1 . you can use another SSOs like CAS or Keyclock and sth.

Comment: @mamJavad Bad advice. His issue comes from a leaky context, and you're suggesting to build a solution around a badly defined domain. The first thing I would ask is - why do you need to validate the token on Microservice B? Especially if communication comes from Microservice A which already validates it. Are you assuming that Microsevice A can lie to you? What are the microservices you're talking about truly responsible for - is Microservice A - Auth, and Microsevice B is what?

Comment: yes you are right microservice a will validate but if he want to validate at microservice B what he have to do ?

Comment: @mamJavad That's a different scenario - the scenario he spoke off is the flow in which Microservice B is called through Microservice A.

If in another scenario both Microservice A and Microservice B have public APIs - then you should create a Gateway API and validate token there. Otherwise you would have both M.A and M.B call `AuthService` to validate the token every time a request is made - which is inefficient to say the least. I write a bit about Gateway API here - https://obeycode.com/articles/7/microservices-in-simple-terms---introduction

Comment: yes it makes sense . you are right

Answer (score 3):

If you need two microservices to communicate witch each other securely the most common way is to have a third part.

Think of it like this, when you are to get a passport with the government, you usually need to bring a family member that will vouch for you and tell you that you are who you claim to be.

So, first you need 3 different parties:

- Authentication Server
- Resource server 1 (Microservice A)
- Resource server 2 (Microservice B)

The flow goes as follows if you are using a JWT:

- Microservice A calls the Authentication server providing their client id and client secret which proves that they are who they claim to be.
- The Authentication server authenticates the client (Microservice A) and then issues a short lived JWT (usually a couple of minutes) which is signed using the private key of the Authentication server.
- Microservice A takes the JWT and calls Microservice B including the token
- Microservice B uses the Authentication service `public key` to verify the signature of the provided JWT.

There are mainly 2 ways for a resource server to get hold of the authentication servers public key. Either you provide it to the server during startup, through maybe a configuration file etc. This usually makes it harder to rotate keys if needed in case of a JWT is leaked or any other security reason.

The other way is to set up so that the authorization server exposes a JWK endpoint, which is a rest endpoint that servers can call to get the public key dynamically.

So for instance all servers might call every 30 minutes to the auth server to get the public key, this means that we can rotate the key and 30 mins later all the servers will automatically get the new key.

So just like in real life, we need a third party an auth server that can vouch for both services.

Comment: This is what's needed, a separate `AuthService`. However, I would suggest avoiding making calls to it in every microservice, as it'll be too chatty, and many people consider this a leaky domain (putting dependency on auth in a domain that should be agnostic). I suggest using a Gateway API and authenticate there - the inner service doesn't need to know whether user is authenticated or not, because for all they care - it can be services consuming themselves without any input from outside world.

Comment: There are pro’s and cons with gateways. If using a gateway you are relying on an outer shell to protect tou, if you manage to bypass this shell you could possibly have access to everything. Ome example would be if i manage to for instance run rogue pods in a cluster, or start custom services in a cloud on the same vpn. Also usually to speed up gateways, they are backed by an in memory cache that holds jwts for quicker requests. This cache needs to be highly protected. Depending on what security level, and acceptable risk, one can choose one over the other.

Comment: Fair point, albeit I need clarification - what do you mean by "bypass" - do you mean omitting the "Gateway API" step completely and accessing services directly or having Gateway API authenticate you regardless of credentials and let the request through?

Comment: i mean running something inside the same wpn and call services directly instead of going by the gateway.

Comment: True, although if somebody got on your VPN - you're in equal amount of trouble, regardless to whether you had a gateway or not. I don't think this issue is inherent to Gateways - in fact, when using Gateways, it's advised to use a request source IP whitelisting, so HTTP traffic can come to service only from the Gateway - which prevents even internal calls (unless whitelisted).

Comment: But if i get remote code execution on a trusted service then i can pass through the gateway. I’m more for a zero trust approach

Comment: I see your point.